# Import Range from spreadsheet but exclude rows with missing data

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 spreadsheets (sheet1 + sheet2)

Sheet2 Pulls in data from Sheet1 using the IMPORTRANGE function which works fine, except that there are a few rows that have missing information in 1-2 columns and for the purpose of what I am trying to do I need to just remove these rows.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Not sure if I need to add something to the IMPORTRANGE function or create a new spreadsheet and use a different function or do I have to manually delete these rows?

Cheers

Comment: I thought they used the same or very similar functions. My bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QUERY function provides this ability. The "IS NOT NULL" argument works with numbers, and "!=" is for Strings (anything that's not just numbers).

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("YourKey","SheetName!A:B");
IMPORTRANGE("YourKey,"SheetName!A:B");},
"SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")
```

Or

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("YourKey","SheetName!A:B");
IMPORTRANGE("YourKey,"SheetName!A:B");},
"SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col2 != ''")
```

Comment: And indeed `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` etc. are the system-provided column names when using `QUERY()` with array literals. The usual `A`, `B`, `C` etc. won't work. Nice find, didn't know! :-)